# Can I have an NSArray containing NSArrays

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

I would like to store multiple values for a label and I have some 10 labels.
So is it possible to have a NSArray of NSArray objects?
Can I do something like this:

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: NSArray1, NSArray2, nil];
```

Comment: Did you try it? You can answer this question by using XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. An NSArray can hold any object subclassed from NSObject. NSArray is subclassed from NSObject. Therefore, an NSArray can hold an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can store any object inside an NSArray, you can store other NSArrays inside just like any other object (i.e. NSNumber, YourCustombObj, etc.).

You can even add NSMutableArrays or NSDictionarys inside NSArrays:

```
NSArray *array = [NSarray alloc] initWithObjects: mutableArray1, dictionary1, nil];
```